# If I follow a post, will the owner be notified it was me?

Tags: facebook, facebook-notifications

I would like to follow posts or photographs of another Facebook member who is not in my friend list (and there is no need for us to become friends), can they see that I have turned on the notifications?

Comment: Do you mean follow a *person* or *turn on notifications* on a post?

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to follow post owner, they will get notified and they can see you anytime in their followers list. But if you are going to turn on notifications on the post, owner will not get notified.

Comment: Dear downvoter, please do not hesitate to leave a comment why did you downvote. It will help me to improve my answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow someone, he/she will get notified once that you followed him/her. You can set priority to see his/her post at first on your feed, this time he/she won't get notified. If you follow a single post of someone this time he/she won't get notified. If you unfollow him/her, he/she won't get notified either.

Answer (score 0):

> If I follow a post

No one will get notified.

> I would like to follow posts or photographs of another Facebook member

Yes, they will get notified. Unless they turned off notifications for new followers.

> can they see that **I** have turned on the notifications?

Depends on the amount of followes they get regularly. If it's important whether or not your name is shown on the notification, I'd like you to follow [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116723/163465).

Comment: This is not correct answer for this question.

Comment: May I ask, what's wrong?

Comment: _can they see that I have turned on the notifications?_ this information. And OP is asking for post not for friend or non-friend or page.

Comment: It's a bit unclear in the Question body. So, I've put emphasis on the "I" part in my blockquote.

Comment: But when we actually look at the title, OP asked “if it was me? So, I think it's correct.

Comment: It is mentioned as _if I follow a post_.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76807/discussion-between-borhnn-and-serenesat).