# Following someone on Facebook - will they get notified?

Tags: facebook, followers, follow

**Following on Facebook:**

1. If I start following someone (like a public figure) - they get notified about new followers?
2. If I un-follow a friend and then re-follow him - will they get notified on any of them?

Sources would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. If I start following someone (like a public figure) - they get notified about new followers?

Yes, they will get notified. Some individual may turn off notification for a new follower. In that case, no.

Now if you're wondering, Will they get a notification like, 
"arieljannai is following you."?

That depends on how many followers they got in the last certain amount of time. It can be from a few hours to a couple of days.

If they get a follower every once in a while they will get the notification:
"arieljannai is following you."

But if it's a popular public figure, they may get a notification:
"John, Jenny and 30 other people started following you"

Where your name may not even be shown. But they can click on the notification or check their follower list later in time and will find you there.

> 2. If I un-follow a friend and then re-follow him - will they get notified on any of them?

When you un-follow someone they will not get a notification. Neither if you re-follow a friend. ([source](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10207504339639988))

Comment: It makes sense. And [here](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10207504339639988)'s the source.

Comment: _That depends on how many followers the get on a regular basis._ whatever you have written about this that is not correct. That depends on time span.

Comment: Sorry, phrasing problem. I'll try to correct it now.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go:

1. **Yes**, when you follow a public figure or a non-friend, a notification will be send to them.
2. **No**, unfollowing or re-following any friend will not send notification to that person.

Check these links to understand about follow and unfollow:
[What does it mean to follow someone or a Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/279614732052951?helpref=about_content)
[How do I follow or unfollow a profile or Page?](https://www.facebook.com/help/276458109035418?helpref=faq_content)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't have a source to it (I know about the following, un-following - just wasn't sure about the notifications thing). Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

They will not be notified for 'follows/unfollows' but they can see the list of people who is following them

Comment: 2) ONLY. I didnt precise it. Sorry